# SQL Server freezes (because of application), need logging

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, slow-log

We have an application running ontop of our SQL Server 2005 instance and a couple of times a week this application (unannounced) will cause the SQL Server to freeze. I can't even restart the SQL Server service; I have to restart the entire machine.

Needless to say, I can't open a query window to run `sp_who2` to find the cause. It could be days before the issue shows up again. Is there any type of logging I can put in place to better track down what is causing the SQL Server to freeze up?

`exec xp_readerrorlog` only shows me what has happened after the restart so it isn't much help.

At the time it freezes, CPU is pegged at 90-97% and memory is maxed at 8 GB. Server has 12 GB but the max is set to 8192 for SQL Server.

Answer (score 8):

SQL Server has a Dedicated Administrative Connection, see [How to: Use the Dedicated Administrator Connection with SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). The DAC uses distinct, pre-reserved resources (memory, CPU, IO ports etc) exactly so it can be used even when the server is 'frozen'. From the DAC you can run queries that can identify the cause of the spike.

When the server is restarted the ERRORLOG is not deleted, it gets recycled. The errorlog from before the shutdown is usually `ERRORLOG.1`, then `ERRORLOG.2` etc, and is located in the same folder as the current one. Just open it and inspect the tail of the file. Your previous restart logs are probably there still, have a look and see what you can find. Also see if there are any `.mdmp` files in the same location...

Comment: +1 DAC + [sp_whoisactive](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx) might give enough for a follow up question that gets closer to the root cause, with minimal effort.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to look into 2 routes that will be most helpful to you in your situation:

1. Monitor PERFMON counter - especially `% Processor Time` along with [SQLDiag](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1863/introduction-to-sqldiag-for-sql-server-performance-monitoring-and-tuning/)

> On a SQL Server 2005 server, the **SQLDiag utility** is present under the following folder as SQLDiag.exe file – [systemroot]\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn. On a SQL Server 2008 box, SQLDiag is present under [systemroot]\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn. SQLDiag uses an XML configuration file which can be used to specify the data that you want to collect.

2. When in doubt, run [process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/). Also [ProcDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) is useful for getting dump of particular process. Very useful tools from sysinternals.

ProcDump has a parameter `-c` for CPU threshold at which to create a dump of the process.

Excellent References :

- SQLBITS presentation by Christian Bolton - [Consolidating data collection with SQLDIAG and analysing it all with SQLNexus](https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event7/Consolidating_data_collection_with_SQLDIAG_and_analysing_it_all_with_SQLNexus)
- [How to use SQLDiag, SQLNexus and PAL tools to analyze performance issues in SQL Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20160221091352/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pamitt/archive/2011/02/25/how-to-use-the-sqldiag-the-sqlnexus-and-the-pal-tools-to-analyze-performance-issues-in-sql-server.aspx)
- [Got High-CPU Usage Problems? ProcDump 'Em!](https://web.archive.org/web/20171102065647/http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/got-high-cpu-usage-problems-procdump-em)

Comment: don't use ProcDump with SQL Server. It has it's own dumper, [`sqldumper.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917825) which does some SQL Server specific tricks. Eg. it can generate a 'filtered' dump which does not contain actual data (buffer pool) for a much, much, much smaller dump *and* a dump which is safe(er) to share with outsiders.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Thanks for mentioning. Really helpful to know.

Comment: With ProcDump (or any other non-SQL Server aware tool for the matter) on a 12GB RAM system you risk dumping an image file of +12GB. Not the end of the world, until you have a 256GB RAM server to deal with...

Comment: I don't think I'd put any form of memory dump and analysis tools in the hands of someone asking this sort of question, frankly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PerfMon to track some SQL Server counters:

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/

I was going to suggest you check the plan cache for the most resource-intensive queries, but that will only show queries since your last reboot.  One of them might point you in the right direction, though.

http://www.brentozar.com/responder/get-top-resource-consuming-queries/

You could also read the error logs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187109%28v=sql.90%29.aspx